# MySQL Stored Procedure returning row of nulls instead of no row at all

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I am working on for a simple AJAX user search.

The procedure is querying based on a few different fields and then using a 'LIKE' to find something based on the search term.

When I return the results, if theres nothing found, it is returning a single row all all `null` instead of no row at all.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchCustomerOrders`(IN in_term varchar(60))
BEGIN
    SELECT  u.first_name as firstName, 
                    u.last_name as lastName, 
                    os.status, 
                    o.orderID, 
                    CASE WHEN COUNT(op.orderID) = 0 THEN null ELSE COUNT(op.orderID) END as qty
    FROM `order` as o
    JOIN order_product as op
    ON o.orderID = op.orderID
    JOIN order_status as os
    ON o.statusID = os.statusID
    JOIN users as u
    ON o.userID = u.ID
    WHERE 
        o.orderID LIKE CONCAT('%', in_term, '%')
        or
        u.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%', in_term, '%')
        or
        u.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', in_term, '%')
        or
        u.last_name + ', ' + u.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', in_term, '%')
        or
        os.status LIKE CONCAT('%', in_term, '%');
END
```

[image]

Any idea how I can return no results if theres no data found?

**Update:**

The issue seems to be with the `COUNT` line. When I remove this from the query, it returns an empty result (the correct behavior).

Comment: This condition should be handled in the application layer, not the database.

Comment: @tadman - The screenshot is me running the query in the database, nothing with the application. Its returning a row of `null` data, rather than an empty result.

Comment: Adding `HAVING COUNT(op.orderID) != 0` at the end may give you the behavior you expect, but then you will find that your query actually has a more fundamental flaw -- the other columns will be randomly populated with values from only one of the matching orders.  It's not clear what this query is supposed to accomplish, because `qty` doesn't seem to make sense in the context of the other columns.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - `order_product` is a table that has all of the items a person purchased in their order. My goal was to tell me how many items were in that order by counting the single line items (one row per product purchased).

Comment: To add to this, the query works perfectly fine with one of the `WHERE` statements actually find data. It shows the correct number of items it found in the order etc. It's when it doesn't meet any condition that the count is becoming an issue.

Comment: @SBB what you should find is that it only actually works correctly when 1 order is matched, not when 2 or more are matched.  You need to `GROUP BY orderID` to fix that logic, and this should take care of the null row as well.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, that seemed to fix it!